# Mixed types in Pyflink stream Map

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-flink, pyflink

Im trying to sink data to ElasticSearch index via Elasticsearch7SinkBuilder, afrer map function beeing applied. Elasticsearch7SinkBuilder (as I understand) expects that output of map would be a `Types.Map`, but I cannot specify what value types suppose to be in my map output, originaly it is python dict with one string, one integer and one dict fields

```
{
  "doc_id": "some",
  "n_field": 1,
  "d_field": {...}
}
```

Is there is the way to specify map output type that match this structure? Or any other way to index this type of document in elsatic via Flink tool?

Im using pyflink version 1.17

I've tried do not provide a Type. It fails during Elasticsearch7SinkBuilder trying to cast it to Map
I've tried a Type.Map without specify types of key and field. It fails because they should be provided.
I've tried Type.Map(Types.STRING(),Types.STRING()). it fails because it not match my output.

I've tried Type.Map(Types.STRING(),Types.STRING()). with cast every field to string and set schema for index in elastic. It fails on checing types

Comment: Please share the code and what you're trying to do and also the errors you're getting.

Comment: `stream.map(lambda doc: {"doc_id": "doc": json.dumps(doc)}, Types.MAP(Types.STRING(), Types.STRING())).sink_to(es7_sink)
    )
` works, but elastic doen't parse doc back to json

`stream.map(lambda doc: {"doc_id": "doc": doc}, Types.MAP(Types.STRING(), Types.STRING())).sink_to(es7_sink)
    )`
Fails becuase it doen't match `Type.Map(Types.STRING(),Types.STRING())`


`stream.map(lambda doc: {"doc_id": "doc": doc}).sink_to(es7_sink)
    )`
Fails becuase it pickles resuslt and (of course) es7_sink not able to unpickle it to Map